# Laravel app hosted within directory shows ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5.1

I have a app developed in Laravel 5.1. It is hosted within directory structure as `public_html/gnrcnew/gnrcadmin` where `gnrcadmin` is Laravel app. But when I tried to access it shows  `ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`. I tried to change the `.htaccess` within `public` directory as :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /gnrcnew/gnrcadmin/public/
    RewriteBase /~gnrcnew/gnrcadmin/public/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But same result appears. My url is [Laravel App](http://web3soft.org/gnrcnew/gnrcadmin/public/). How can I remove this error ?

`storage` directory `777` permission : [image: Storage permission from FTP]

Comment: Is storage directory having right permissions?

Answer (score 2):

The thing that you are trying to do is to access the `/storage` folder just without read write permissions which is required by laravel.

> #### Using File Manager
>
> One of the easy and basic ways to change the permissions is through File manager in cPanel. To change the permissions for a file or folder in cpanel, please do the following:
>
> 1. Click File Manager
> 2. Click the name of the file for which you would like to change the permissions.
> 3. Select the Change Permissions link at the top right of the page.
> 4. Select the permissions you would like to set for the file.
> 5. Click Change Permissions
>
> #### Using FTP
>
> Connect to FTP. Go to the file and right click. Choose Permissions or Attributes or Properties (depends on your program).
>
> #### Using SSH or a script
>
> This can be done with chmod command.

From [HostGator](http://support.hostgator.in/articles/cpanel/how-to-change-permissions-chmod-of-a-file) website which is most probably your hosting provider.

**EDIT**: The directory should have the recursive mode enabled. You are not just giving permissions to one directory, but you are giving it to each and every subdirectory that you find inside that folder. If you still see an error, please post last few errors from your logs.(If it's stored which might not be there).

Comment: And yeah I think he is "most probably" using hostgator because the error is giving a hostgator page.

Comment: OP => "Original Post" or "Original Poster".

Comment: Thanks and maybe you got your answer @Sparky

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have given `storage` directory `777` permissions. Please check the screenshot at edited question

Comment: Is it recursive? Because storage does not need to be writable, but folders  that inside has to be (app, framework, logs)

Comment: Yeah @Valdas is right @Nitish. You need to check the option that you see `Recurse into SubDirectories`.

Comment: I checked twice  @AdityaGiri, its recursively writable :(

Comment: Well maybe in that case check what is your php version. I saw some other questions and saw that even that makes difference